# Solve the equation similar to the Kummer equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

**In my calculations, I arrived at the differential equation below. What should I do to solve this equation, which is similar to the Kummer equation? Can the Kummer equation be obtained by changing the variable?**
$$yF^{''}+(Ay+B)F^{'}+CF=0 $$
that Kummer differential equation is, $xy^{''}+(b-x)y^{'}-ay=0$
thank you

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can the solution of equation be considered as a hypergeometric function of the second kind only? Given that the second kind of hypergeometric function (Tricomi confluent function)is written in terms of the function of the first kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct! This differential equation can most certainly be transformed to the Kummer equation.

We assume that such a transformation exists. We will make a simple change of variables and let $y=\alpha x$ for some constant $\alpha$ to be determined. This gives us

$$\frac{d}{dy}=\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d}{dx}$$

If we assign $F(y)=G(x)$, then

$$F'(y)=\frac{1}{\alpha}G'(x),\;\;\;\;F''(y)=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}G''(x)$$

This transforms the equation to

$$\frac{x}{\alpha}G''+\left(A\alpha x+B\right)\frac{1}{\alpha}G'+CF=0$$

We multiply this by $\alpha$ to get

$$xG''+(A\alpha x+B)G'+C\alpha G=0$$

To look like the Kummer differential equation, we require $A\alpha=-1$, and so we assign $\alpha=-\frac{1}{A}$. This now creates

$$xG''+(B-x)G'-\frac{C}{A}G=0$$

which is the Kummer differential equation with parameters $B$ and $C/A$. The solution of the first kind is

$$G(x)=M\left(\frac{C}{A},B,x\right)$$

depending on your notation. Replacing this with the previous variable, we have

$$F(y)=M\left(\frac{C}{A},B,-\frac{y}{A}\right)$$

The solution of the second kind is similar. My knowledge of hypergeometric functions is lacking at this point, but I believe that this is what you are at least looking for. I hope this helps!